# Select specific text from content editable div

Tags: javascript, html, css

consider below content editable div

```css
.editable-div div {
display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" class="editable-div">
  <div> This </div> <div> is a an example</div><div> for inline block</div> <div>elemenst </div> 
</div>
```

1. Put mouse cursor on anywhere in the content
2. Press shift+home
3. It will select only inline-block div content
4. I want to select the whole content till beginning of the div
5. I can not change **inline-block** style of inner divs
6. Due to above reason(5) I am doing an custom implementation for shift+home and shift+ end, that is why I need to select specific text from a div

*Select as In text selection (user-select) of browser, I already have links for selecting whole content of a div [Selecting text in an element (akin to highlighting with your mouse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

but here I want to select specific text only. please help

Comment: How will you know that you need to select only `test editable cont` ? Is there any pattern or rule to select that?

Comment: Specifically: Are you interested in finding a specific set of characters (string) or matching a regular expression:?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text.

Answer (score 0):

I think `window.getSelection()` is what you're looking for.

```
var selection = "";

function getText() {
  if (window.getSelection) {
    selection = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type !== "Control") {
    selection = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  return text;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text

Comment: Sorry, I want to select the text , don;t want to retrieve it